# Getting "error cannot stat" messages in Windows when attempting to switch branches

Tags: git, windows-10, permission-denied, git-checkout, git-for-windows

I am new to Git and have been running smoothly until this snag. I have just worked on a branch `b1` and committed a number of changes, mostly involving moving files around to different folders. I then did

```
git push
git checkout master
git push
```

and everything was fine. Then I tried to do

```
git checkout b1
```

and I get a huge list of errors for all the files I recently changed, each one saying:

```
error: cannot stat '....': Permission denied
```

I look in my directory and it seems to be a weird mix of the old folders I should have in `master` right now (the old ones) and then new folders that should only appear if `b1` is checked out, which when I try to click on them deny me axis. Seems like things are stuck in a limbo state.

Rebooting fixed the problem, but I want to know the source of the issue so that I don't need to resort to that if it happens regularly, or at least how I can avoid it.

I'm running Windows 10 on a laptop and pushing to GitHub.

Comment: I was working with Windows 10 Ubuntu subsystem and while my Node.Js app was running on it, I found that all files was locked when trying to change branch with Git. So it's probably an opened application that cause your permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you've figured this out, but if you're running backend (python) or frontend (angular) services be sure to stop them as these processes may created this lock scenario.